# How can I prevent a split at a quoted comma using .split?

Tags: javascript, split

I'm looking to split a string that is comma separated.
The array1 is populated from a string of rows got in a .csv file.

Array2 then splits this into seperate values.  It works fine, but not if I have a comma inside quotes.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    array2.push(array1[i].split(","));      
}
```

i.e.

```
array1[0] = abcde, defg, hijkl;
array1[1] = abcde, "def,ghi" , jklmn;
```

should become

```
array2[0]....
array2[1][0] = abcde
array2[1][1] = def,ghi
array2[1][2] = jklmn
```

How can I prevent a split at the quoted comma?

Comment: You'll have to write a full-blown CSV parser. You can't blindly apply a regex to csv and hope to get good results.

Comment: CSV parsing is a common task. I would use a third-party library that has the edge cases handled and move on.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

Answer (score 0):

Use a look ahead in your regex:

```
split(",(?=(([^\"]*\"){2})*[^\"]*$)")
```

This splits only on commas followed by an *even* number of quotes (those followed by an *odd* number must be *within* quotes).